# Ionic 2 Cannot find Deploy

Tags: cordova, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I just followed ionic docs to set up Ionic Deploy on an app but I still get this error: **Cannot find name 'Deploy'**. 
Instructions followed: http://docs.ionic.io/services/deploy/ 
My code in main component (app.component.ts):

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Deploy } from '@ionic/cloud-angular';
import { Nav, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';


import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { EventPage } from '../pages/event/event';
import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';
import { ProfilePage } from '../pages/profile/profile';

import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
import { UpcomingEventsPage } from "../pages/upcoming-events/upcoming-events";
import { CoursesService } from "../services/courses.service.";

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

  availableUpdate: boolean = false;

  rootPage: any = HomePage;
  loading: boolean = false;

  pages: Array<{ title: string, component: any, params: any }>;

  constructor(
        public platform: Platform, 
        public statusBar: StatusBar, 
        public splashScreen: SplashScreen,
        public coursesService: CoursesService,
        private authService: AuthService
        ,public deploy: Deploy
        ) {
    this.initializeApp();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just needed to install prerequisites: angular-cloud.